# How do I remove the first character from a link's text with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, string

I want to remove first character from  link's text with jQuery.

```
<span class="test1"> +123.23 </span>
<span class="test2"> -13.23 </span>
```

I want to remove the "+" and "-" from  with jQuery.

Output:

```
<span class="test1"> 123.23 </span>
<span class="test2"> 13.23 </span>
```

Comment: What code have you written for this and what was the result for your homework assignment?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
var val = $("span").html();
$("span").html(val.substring(1, val.length));
```

Comment: Downvoted a step back: 1) this replaces the value of all span elements with the value of the first span element. 2) this example has a syntax error.

Comment: Your starting index is incorrect. Should be 2. Also, you need to add a leading space to the new value since that's what's needed in the output.

Comment: This answer is needlessly complicated. Why not just do $('span').html().substring(1)?

Comment: @Ryan is all right! His way it's much more simplified =D Thanks =)

Comment: and why use .html()?  This would cause issues if you had nested elements as it would just stripped the '<' from the opening tag of the nested element.  .text() as @cletus used would address this issue.

Answer (score 25):

```
$("span.test1, span.test2").each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/[+-]/, ""));
});
```

Comment: +1 substring is the bad way of doing this. Despite the author's answer tick.. this answer using Regex is the right answer!

Comment: @Evildonald: why substring is bad ? I agree that it's better to use Regex, but I won't call substring bad :-)

Comment: Why is Regex better? If you know where the substitution needs to happen, substring is better than Regex from both a performance and readability standpoint.

Answer (score 7):

```
// get the current text
text1 = $(".test1").html();
// set the text to the substring starting at the third character
$(".test1").html(text1.substring(2)); // extract to the end of the string

text2 = $(".test2").html();
$(".test2").html(" " + text2.substring(2)); // looks like you want to keep the leading space
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get/set the HTML using .html() and remove the first character using .substring(), I  think it's pretty clear now, you just need to write a 2 (or 3) lines code.