# How to remove first 3 letters in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove the first three letters of a string in JQuery?

For example: Turn `cat1234` to `1234`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684939/how-do-i-remove-the-first-character-from-a-links-text-with-jquery

Answer (score 106, accepted):

No jQuery needed.

```
"cat1234".slice(3);
```

or

```
"cat1234".substring(3);
```

or

```
"cat1234".substr(3);
```

```js
var str="cat1234";
console.log("using slice =",str.slice(3));
console.log("using substring =",str.substring(3));
console.log("using substr =",str.substr(3));
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var val = 'cat1234';
var newVal = val.substring(3, val.length);
```

Comment: @Martin : I have checked that its working fine... check it then do downvote.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need jQuery to do this, JavaScript will do:

```
"cat1235".substring(3) // yields 1235
```

Answer (score 4):

Use javascript's [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yntwf/)

```
var str = "cat123";
alert(str.substr(3));
```

Comment: Question doesn't ask for the value to be `alert`ed

Comment: That's just for a demo purposes, and doesn't hurt

Answer (score 4):

How about vanilla javascript:

```
'cat1234'.slice(3)
# returns '1234'
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use jquery to do that, use simple javascript:

```
var txt = 'cat1234';
var txt2 = txt.substr(3);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function trimCat() { return "cat1234".substring(3, 6); }
```

or

```
function trimAnotherCat() { return "cat1234".replace("cat", ""); }
```

Comment: seriously, where has all the love gone?

Comment: The snippet you posted is wrong and can be used only in functions. alert is correct one..

Comment: @BobTodd: Balance restored, this is a more than perfectly valid answer :). @Martin: `alert()` is no more valid than `return` in this context...OP has not actually specified what they want

Comment: @Martin: What if the OP doesn't want an alert box? You're just guessing, which is no more valid than BobTodd's guess of using `return` from a function. End of story.

Comment: @Clive ah, arbitration. i now feel all warm and valid :]

Comment: @Bob okay, if you edit your answer, (it's "locked" now), I can remove my downvote.

Comment: I'd quibble with the second formulation; you need to know the first three letters were "cat."
I think you were just trying to live up to the aphorism that there's more than one way to trim a cat.

Answer (score 3):

```
var cat1234 = 'cat1234';
var new1234 = cat1234.substring(3);
```

Comment: in this case it should be cate1234.substring(3);

Answer (score 2):

Just plain JavaScript:

```
var s = 'cat1234';
console.log(s.substr(3));
```

All String methods can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = 'cat1234';
var newStr = str.slice(3);
```

it works for me. `slice(3)` will slice first 3 character from string.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can do the trick.

```
var s = 'cat1234';

console.log(s.toString().slice(3));
```

This will output: **1234**