# remove # inside a href attribute of an anchor tag how

Tags: javascript, jquery

im making a tab and the concept is when a person click on the tab menu, jquery will then check on the href attribute of that anchor tag (tab menu) and remove # inside it and leaves the rest attr content of that attribute (href). for example

```
<a href="#home" class="tabmenu">Tab 1</a><a href="#inventory" class="tabmenu>Tab 2</a>
<div id="home" class="tab">content of tab 1 here</div>
<div id="inventory" class="tab">content of tab 2 here</div>
```

so when one of the tab menu is clicked. jquery will remove the # of that anchor tag href attribute, therefore the href attribute will be this href="home" (if tab 1 is click) and then jquery will hide all tab content div first (.tab) and then show the content tab that has #home (if tab 1 is click).

so the script concept will somehow look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabmenu').click(function(){
        //get the anchor tag attr
        //remove # inside this anchor tag href attribute and the remaining content will be put in a variable
        //hide all tab content first
        //get the stored variable and then show the tab content that match of that stored variable e.g. (home or inventory).
    });
});
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove the first character from a link's text with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684939/how-do-i-remove-the-first-character-from-a-links-text-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the show only the matching content when the user click the tabs, you can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.tabmenu').click(function(){
        //hide all:
        $(".tab").hide();
        //show clicked tab:
        $("#" + $(this).attr('href').substring(1)).show();
    });
});
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x29gn8yo/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to change the href attribute, it's not even necessary for what you're doing, but maybe you need this for something else, so here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabmenu').click(function(){

        //get the anchor tag attr
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        //remove # inside this anchor tag href attribute and the remaining content will be put in a variable
        if (href[0] == '#') {
            this.attr('href') = href.substring(1);
        }

        //hide all tab content first
        $('.tab').hide();

        //get the stored variable and then show the tab content that match of that stored variable e.g. (home or inventory).
        $(href).show();
    });
});
```

Please be aware that this code only works once for every link since we change the href attribute. I can modify it to work with the changed attribute if you want to.